# Comparing the keys of one dictionary with the values of another

Tags: python, dictionary, key

So, I have two dictionaries. Both are created from a txt-file with different Documents.
The first dictionary has as its keys the Document-Id and as the corresponding value the document itself.
The second dictionary has as keys every word of all the documents and as value a 1.
I want increase the value of every key in the second dictionary by 1, everytime a word comes up inside the values of a key of Dictionary one that matches a key in the second dictionary.
As an example:

```
dict1 = {'Doc-Id1' : ['It', 'was', 'summertime'], 'Doc-Id2' : ['It', 'is', 'night', 'o', 'dark', 'night']}
dict2 = {'It' : 1, 'was' : 1, 'summertime' : 1, 'is' : 1, 'night': 1, 'o' : 1, 'dark': 1}
```

should change to

```
dict2 = {'It' : 2, 'was' : 1, 'summertime' : 1, 'is' : 1, 'night': 2,'o' : 1, 'dark': 1}
```

as the "It" and "night" can be found two times in dict1.

Can somebody help me out here? I dont have any idea, how to accomplish this task

I tried some comprehensions but I cant find any why to compare the keys of one dictionary with the values of another.

Comment: Iterate through `dict1.values()`, extract words from each value and use them as keys in `dict2`.

Comment: I already have my dict2 with the keys. But I want to change the values of dict2 depending on how often the key matches a word in dict1

Comment: You can use something like `dict2[word] += 1` to increment the value associated with the key contained in `word`.

Comment: Syntax for `dict1` dict definition is incorrect.

Comment: What do you mean? In my example code?

Comment: Yes. If the values would be strings, they would need quotes.

Comment: Okay, thanks. The values are lists, therefore i made an edit now to show that

Comment: This is syntactically incorrect, too. You should first work through the [Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/) if not done yet.

Comment: `[It was summertime]`: `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`. You have to decide `"It was summertime"` or `["It"; "was"; "summertime"]`

Comment: Yes, my OCaml habits has got me. Read `["It", "was", "summertime"]`

Comment: I apologize, I made another edit, this is how it is also on my console

Comment: My idea was, that every word already exists at least once in the documents, as both dictionary come from the same document collection. But you are of course correct, this is really embarassing. But could you give me an idea, how I could still increase  the value, if the values in dict1 are lists, as seen in my question?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions and your comments, next time I will be more carefull with my question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following program works like described:

```
dict1 = {'Doc-Id1' : ['It', 'was', 'summertime'], 'Doc-Id2' : ['It', 'is', 'night', 'o', 'dark', 'night']}
dict2 = {'It' : 1, 'was' : 1, 'summertime' : 1, 'is' : 1, 'night': 1, 'o' : 1, 'dark': 1}

for v in dict1.values():
    for w in v:
        dict2[w] += 1
```

But the values are different (you have 2 "It", then the "It" value is increment twice from 1, which makes 3 not 2).

This program needs the `dict2`to contains all the needs words (else a key error is raised).

If you want to proceed with extra words:

```
for v in dict1.values():
    for w in v:
        try:
            dict2[w] += 1
        except KeyError:
            dict2[w] = 1
```

Comment: When I try this, it gives me AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: It works with me, but I have rewritten `dict1 = {'Doc-Id1' : "x It was summertime", 'Doc-Id2' : "It is night o dark night"}` (with `"`). `dict.values()` is the list of sentences, then each `v` is a string, and we can write `v.split`. I have seen that you have edited the question. Then my answer can't work anymore. NOte that you still have to write strings with `"`

Comment: Thank you for your sugggestion, I apologize that I gave a wrong example, I edited the question again

Comment: Yes, its question is ambiguous. He wants to increase the value of every key in the second dictionary by 1, everytime a word comes up inside the values of a key of Dictionary that matches a key in the second dictionary... And When "It" is seen 2 times, it increase the dictionary 2 times.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this one worked